# How to swap array index in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$order_total_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` WHERE order_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order ASC");
```

If i print the result, It shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => shipping
            [title] => UK Shipping  (Weight: 0.00kg)
            [value] => 10.2000
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => sub_total
            [value] => 4.7000
            [sort_order] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => coupon
            [title] => Coupon (10P)
            [value] => -0.4700
            [sort_order] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => tax
            [title] => VAT (20%)
            [value] => 2.8860
            [sort_order] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => total
            [title] => Total
            [value] => 17.3160
            [sort_order] => 9
        )
    )
```

After that,

```
foreach ($order_total_query->rows as $total)
  {
   $text .= $total['title'] . ': ' . html_entity_decode($this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
  }
```

If I print `$text`, It shows :

```
Order Totals
UK Shipping  (Weight: 4.00kg): £10.20
Sub-Total: £18.80
coupon : £-0.47
VAT (20%): £5.80
Total: £34.80
```

But I want to interchange the position of Sub-Total and Coupon, when coupon is not empty.I need the result as below:

```
Order Totals
UK Shipping  (Weight: 4.00kg): £10.20           
coupon : £-0.47
Sub-Total: £18.80
VAT (20%): £5.80
Total: £34.80
```

Comment: the array you have presented doesn't have keys `currency_code` and `currency_value`, mistake?

Comment: currency_code = £0.00, currency_value = £1.00

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique.

```
$temp = $order_total_query[1];
$order_total_query[1] = $order_total_query[2];
$order_total_query[2] = $temp;

print_r($order_total_query)
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => shipping
            [title] => UK Shipping  (Weight: 0.00kg)
            [value] => 10.2000
            [sort_order] => 1
        )    

    [1] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => coupon
            [title] => Coupon (10P)
            [value] => -0.4700
            [sort_order] => 4
        )
    [2] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => sub_total
            [value] => 4.7000
            [sort_order] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => tax
            [title] => VAT (20%)
            [value] => 2.8860
            [sort_order] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (                                
            [order_id] => 1318
            [code] => total
            [title] => Total
            [value] => 17.3160
            [sort_order] => 9
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the order code index.

```
$orderCodes = [
    'sub_shipping' => '',
    'Coupon' => '',
    'sub_total' => '',
    'tax' => '',
    'Total' => ''
];
foreach ($order_total_query->rows as $total) {
    $orderCodes[$total['code']] = $total['title'] . ': ' . html_entity_decode($this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if (empty($orderCodes['Coupon'])) {
    unset($orderCodes['Coupon'])
}
explode('\n', $orderCodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need something like (execute once):

```
UPDATE DB_PREFIX SET sort_order=2 WHERE code = 'coupon'
```

It will reorder them, but take care: who knows where else sort_order used - check it twice before execute.

Also you must find where sort_order sets to 4 (for coupon code) and also change it to 2 for future orders.